# Add top property on redirect a page

Tags: jquery, scroll

Below are my add I want to add scroll the page top. Scroll top working fine ( $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(getid).offset().top - 120 }, 1000); ) with id when passing only id in url but when using full url /main-page/a#id_1 its no working. I am using fixed header so section I want getting hide. how I can add scroll top with full url redirect

```
<a href="/main-page/x">XX</a>
<div class="subcategories">
<div class="subcategories-link"><a href="/main-page/a#id_1">AA</a></div>
<div class="subcategories-link"><a href="/main-page/a#id_2">BB</a></div>
<div class="subcategories-link"><a href="/main-page/a#id_3">CC</a></div>
<div class="subcategories-link"><a href="/main-page/a#id_4">DD</a></div>
<div class="subcategories-link"><a href="/main-page/a#id_5">EE</a></div>
</div>`
```

javascript:

```
$('.subcategories a').each(function(e) {
        $(this).on("click", function() {
            var getid = $(this).attr('href');
             //$("body").scrollTop(500);
            //$(document).scrollTop(100);
            //alert(getid);
            /*$('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(getid).offset().top - 120
            }, 1000);*/
        });
    });

});



$("body").scrollTop(500);
```

Comment: When you use a full href, that page loads - it looks like it's the same page, but it's still a page reload (monitor the Network tab in the browser tools (F12)).  If you don't want it to jump to the anchor (eg #id_4) then remove that from the url.  It's hard to tell your use-case as you have a link to an anchor (so the page would load and scroll to that anchor) but then you say you want it to scroll to the top; so just don't link to an anchor.

Comment: /main-page/x is diff page so suppose i m on the page and click any page /main-page/a need to point on the div

Answer (score 0):

If you not scrollin on same page, but loading different page who has #
you should run this after body loaded

```
    if(window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if ($(hash).length>0) {
            scrollToEl(hash, 220);
        }
    }

    function scrollToEl(target, offset) {
        var $target = $(target);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $target.offset().top - (offset + 70)}, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: How I can scroll all div up-to $target.offset().top -120. on 
Click on url with #id_4 & #id_5 scroll page lessor to fixed header  but rest link scroll fine

Comment: Something like: 
var headerHeight = $("div#header").height();

scrollTop: $target.offset().top - headerHeight